# Google maps MarkerImage sprite is blank (invisible, transparent)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using an image sprite to define the MarkerImage for a Google maps (v3) Marker object. The sprite image is 100 pixels down the image from 0,0 (top left). Code as follows:

```
(function () {
    var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
       "//localhost:8000/public/img/sprite.png",
        new google.maps.Size(25, 25),
        new google.maps.Point(0, -100));
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(39.27, -105.99);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({icon: icon, position: position});
    marker.setMap(map);
}());
```

This code is correct. Yet, the marker image does not display.

*Note: I have discovered the solution to this issue. I am creating this question because it has not yet been answered here. It may save someone a lot of time, as it would have for me.*

Answer (score 0):

For some absurd reason, Google expects a positive y-axis value to traverse down (negatively, plot graphically speaking) the image sprite.

If you would set a background position of (0, -100) in your css, you must pass (0, 100) to Google.

Comment: The documentation states clearly that: origin: Point:The position of the image within a sprite, if any. **By default, the origin is located at the top left corner of the image (0, 0)**. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerImage

Comment: That supports my argument. On a graph, right is positive Y, down is negative X. Using CSS background-position, following standard practice, right is positive Y, down is negative X.

Comment: No, the horizontal axis, (right-left), is the x-axis, the vertical,(up-down), is the y-axis.